# Грамматические основы в предложении:

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор, основа

Немцы все силы сосредоточили именно там, где будут переправляться наши войска.

В главной части грамматическая основа: *Немцы сосредоточили*,
в придаточной: *войска будут переправляться*

Верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, верно. Все силы - дополнение - в главной части, наши - определение в придаточной части.